# Latex two column text figures bad positioning

Tags: graphics, two-column, double-sided

I have two figures each of which has two part a and b. However, their position in the page is not good and they are not in the center. This is my Latex code. How can I make them to be located more symmetric?

```
\documentclass{sig-alternate-05-2015}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}
 \begin{figure*}[tbh]
\centering
\subfloat[][]{
    \includegraphics[width=3.25in]
    {figures/gini.pdf}
  \label{fig:gini}
}%
\qquad
\subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[width=3.25in]
{figures/coverage.pdf}
\label{fig:coverage}
}%
\caption{Trade-off between nDCG and (a) gini and (b) catalog coverage for different $\lambda$.}%
\label{fig:hist}
\end{figure*}

\begin{figure*}[tbh]
\centering
\subfloat[][]{
    \includegraphics[width=3.25in]
    {figures/lo.pdf}
  \label{fig:lorenzCluster}
}%
\qquad
\subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[width=3.25in]
{figures/lo2.pdf}
\label{fig:lorenz}
}%
\caption{Lorenz curve for the (a) items recommended from each cluster and (b) total items recommended.}%
\label{fig:hist}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

Here are figures:

[image: figures]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please, transform your code sniped to complete, small documents starting with `\documentclass{...} and ending with `\end{document}`. Text in document you can simulate with `lipsum` package. Help us to help you!

Comment: with demo figures (`\usepackage[demo]{graphicx`) i obtain nice and symmetrical aligned images in figures. This means, that your images have white space around. To see this, try to add frames around your images: `\fbox{\includegraphics[width=3.25in]
{figures/coverage.pdf}}`

Comment: Thanks. Yes there are white spaces. What should I do?

Comment: I would redraw images with `pgfplots` (their quality is rather low in doesn't have the same looks). Since image are relatively simple, this is not difficult to do. However, you can trim images with options for `\includegraphics`, for example `\includegraphics[trim=<left> <bottom> <right> <top>, ...]{...}`. for details see documentation for package `graphicx`

Comment: I actually used \fbox for all of them and now they look symmetric. Thanks

Comment: Are this means that your problem is solved? Anyway, consider to redraw images ...

Comment: @Zarko I'd question the `quite simple to do`. If you already know how to use `pgfplots`, yes. If you've never used Ti*k*Z, `pgfplots` or similar, not.

Comment: Yes it is solved. How can I mark your answer as the right answer? Although it is a comment.

Comment: @Zarko You have mail ^^.

Comment: @cfr, with *simple* i try to encourage OP to start learning `pgfplots` :) . I intended to close the question as *solved by comments* or as *unclear what you're asking*, but now it seems that I can draw an example of OP images :)

Comment: What is pgfplots? :) And why I should learn it?

Comment: @Zarko But it is very far from simple and why should the OP learn it if they have no particular use for it? @ OP It is a package built on PGF/Ti*k*Z for drawing plots in LaTeX. PGF/Ti*k*Z are packages for drawing things more generally in LaTeX, including, as it happens, plots. `pgfplots` offers a more powerful and somewhat different approach. PGF/Ti*k*Z also enables you to draw a bunch of non-plot-like things.

Comment: If you have to draw a lot of plots or integration into your document is very important or you want higher quality and don't like the other solutions available, then `pgfplots` may be worth learning. Possibly. If you like that kind of thing.

Comment: I usually use R for this purpose but I will definitely have a look at pgfplots. I just searched and saw som examples of it and it looks very interesting. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let convert my comments to an answer:

- test with `demo` options of `graphicx` package show, that you poroblem arise from white space around your images. To see this, add frame around images:

`\fbox{\includegraphics[width=3.25in]{figures/coverage.pdf}}`

- white space around images can be trimmed with `includegraphics` option `trim`:

> [image: Blockquote]

`\includegraphics[trim=<left> <bottom> <right> <top>, ...]{...}`

or even beer to redraw diagrams for example with `pgfplot`. Since diagrams are relatively simple, the learning of `pgfplots` -- if you not familiar with it -- is not so difficult (well, bunch of comments above says opposite :( ) .

An example of redrawing, which can serve for all similar diagrams, is:

[image]

Code for above image is:

```
\documentclass[tikz,
               border=3mm
               ]{standalone}% 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14,
% common options for graphs 
    width=0.45\linewidth,
    grid=both,
    minor grid style={very thin,gray!10},
    every axis label/.append style={font=\small\sffamily},
    scaled ticks=false,
    every tick label/.append style={font=\scriptsize\sffamily,
                                    /pgf/number format/precision=3,
                                    /pgf/number format/fixed},
            }
\usetikzlibrary{intersections, patterns}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
% specific options 
minor tick num=4,
xlabel={Gini},
ylabel={nDCG@10},
xmin=70, xmax=85,
ymin=0.01, ymax=0.05,
                    ]
\addplot coordinates   { (72.5,0.025) (73.0,0.027) (73.5,0.027)
                         (75.0,0.018) (76.0,0.031) (79.0,0.039)
                         (82.0,0.041) (83.8,0.039) (84.2,0.047)
                        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Coordinates is estimated from your image and should be adjusted to correct values. To adopt to others image you need to change coordinates and in case of more curves in graph for each of them add `addplot` command with belonging coordinates.

If it is worth to learn `pgfplots? Depends. In comments are some thoughts (pros and cons) about this, also are some other proposition ... I only like to encourage to start learning. You newer know, when this will more than welcome at some of your future projects, articles etc. In first you can search for similar graphs here on site or look in package documentation and then accommodate closest example to your specifics ... and if you will stuck in drawing, ask here for help.